# jQuery UI css doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've just watched a youtube video about jQuery-UI and here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrHpzNMlhfo

and so I saw that we can try it also with this link:
http: //jsbin.com/chromebug/4

but the result turn me crazy, I really dont have any idea about it

[image: and my chrome version is 57.0.]2987.133

Comment: and im using chrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect the answer that was posted will address this. If not, please review your console and edit your post so that it is easier to see the issue. Include a code example, see more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with jquery-ui.theme.css. It's failed to load, check in the console.

Either you check & correct the googleapi link 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

or else use 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css

[JS Bin Link](http://jsbin.com/gitusaveyo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

```
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```